# Metal: linear texture filtering not working as expected

Tags: ios, metal

I'm using Metal on iOS with the following fragment shader:

```
constexpr sampler s(coord::normalized,
                    address::clamp_to_zero,
                    filter::linear);

fragment half4 passThroughFragment(VertexInOut inFrag [[stage_in]],
                                   texture2d<float> tex [[ texture(0) ]])
{
    return half4(tex.sample(s, inFrag.uv));
}
```

My texture is a 4x4 image. Despite the filtering set to linear, I get the following image, with nearest neighbor filtering:

[image: Image with nearest neighbor filtering]

It seems that my uv's are fine, since when I modify the fragment shader as follows:

```
return half4(0, inFrag.uv.x, inFrag.uv.y, 1);
```

I get the expected image:

[image: Plot of UV coordinates]

**Is there something else I need to do for linear filtering to work other than specify `filter::linear`?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears linear filtering isn't supported for textures of type `MTLPixelFormatRGBA32Float` on my device (iPad Pro). When I change to `MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm`, filtering works as expected.

Comment: If you aren't already aware, you can check Apple's [Metal Pixel Format Capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/metal/capabilities/) table. You'd be looking for "Filter" or "All" in the row for the format you're working with, in the column for your feature set (which is grouped by OS and version).